# Given a 2nd rank tensor as a function of 2D coordinate. Is it possible to express a new "rotated" tensor in the same basis?

Tags: linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, tensors, rotations

I have a 2nd rank tensor $M(x,y)$ (basically a 2 by 2 matrix) and I want to find the expression of a new "rotated" tensor $N(x,y)$ with the following informations:

I have the 2D vector fields $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$ that follows:
$$b(x,y) = M(x,y)\,a(x,y)$$

I want to find the tensor N(x,y) "rotated" by an angle $\theta$ that satisfies:
$$\,b(x',y')=N(x,y)\,a(x',y')$$

with $$R = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix},\qquad \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=R\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$

Is that even possible or do I need more information?

Comment: Usually, a vector field $v(x,y)$ is not rotated by plugging in the rotated point $(x',y')\,.$ (This is how we rotate scalars.) If this is *really* what you want then, obviously $b(x',y')=M(x',y')\,a(x',y')$ but I doubt this has anything to do with geometry.

Comment: I think found what I wanted: $N=R\,M\left(R^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}\right)$